# Getting error in hack/update-all.sh script

Tags: kubernetes

I have been trying to run ./hack/update-all.sh script and I am getting this error while updating codegen:

```
$ ./hack/update-all.sh 
Running in the silent mode, run with -v if you want to see script logs.
Running in short-circuit mode; run with -a to force all scripts to run.
Updating generated-protobuf
Updating codegen
# runtime
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux_generic.go:12: _SS_DISABLE redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux.go:8
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux_generic.go:13: _NSIG redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux.go:9
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux_generic.go:14: _SI_USER redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux.go:10
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux_generic.go:15: _SIG_BLOCK redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux.go:11
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux_generic.go:16: _SIG_UNBLOCK redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux.go:12
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux_generic.go:17: _SIG_SETMASK redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux.go:13
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux_generic.go:18: _RLIMIT_AS redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux.go:14
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux_generic.go:24: sigset redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux.go:20
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux_generic.go:26: rlimit redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux.go:22
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic1.go:11: paniclk redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:552
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic1.go:11: too many errors
!!! Error in /home/peeyush/work/kubernetes/hack/lib/golang.sh:435
  'go install "${goflags[@]:+${goflags[@]}}" -ldflags "${goldflags}" "${nonstatics[@]:+${nonstatics[@]}}"' exited with status 2
Call stack:
  1: /home/peeyush/work/kubernetes/hack/lib/golang.sh:435 kube::golang::build_binaries_for_platform(...)
  2: /home/peeyush/work/kubernetes/hack/lib/golang.sh:574 kube::golang::build_binaries(...)
  3: /home/peeyush/work/kubernetes/hack/build-go.sh:26 main(...)
Exiting with status 1
!!! Error in /home/peeyush/work/kubernetes/hack/lib/golang.sh:494
  '( kube::golang::setup_env; echo "Go version: $(go version)"; local host_platform; host_platform=$(kube::golang::host_platform); local goflags goldflags; eval "goflags=(${KUBE_GOFLAGS:-})"; goldflags="${KUBE_GOLDFLAGS:-} $(kube::version::ldflags)"; local use_go_build; local -a targets=(); local arg; for arg in "$@";
do
    if [[ "${arg}" == "--use_go_build" ]]; then
        use_go_build=true;
    else
        if [[ "${arg}" == -* ]]; then
            goflags+=("${arg}");
        else
            targets+=("${arg}");
        fi;
    fi;
done; if [[ ${#targets[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
    targets=("${KUBE_ALL_TARGETS[@]}");
fi; local -a platforms=("${KUBE_BUILD_PLATFORMS[@]:+${KUBE_BUILD_PLATFORMS[@]}}"); if [[ ${#platforms[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
    platforms=("${host_platform}");
fi; local binaries; binaries=($(kube::golang::binaries_from_targets "${targets[@]}")); local parallel=false; if [[ ${#platforms[@]} -gt 1 ]]; then
    local gigs; gigs=$(kube::golang::get_physmem); if [[ ${gigs} -ge ${KUBE_PARALLEL_BUILD_MEMORY} ]]; then
        kube::log::status "Multiple platforms requested and available ${gigs}G >= threshold ${KUBE_PARALLEL_BUILD_MEMORY}G, building platforms in parallel"; parallel=true;
    else
        kube::log::status "Multiple platforms requested, but available ${gigs}G < threshold ${KUBE_PARALLEL_BUILD_MEMORY}G, building platforms in serial"; parallel=false;
    fi;
fi; if [[ "${parallel}" == "true" ]]; then
    kube::log::status "Building go targets for ${platforms[@]} in parallel (output will appear in a burst when complete):" "${targets[@]}"; local platform; for platform in "${platforms[@]}";
    do
        ( kube::golang::set_platform_envs "${platform}"; kube::log::status "${platform}: go build started"; kube::golang::build_binaries_for_platform ${platform} ${use_go_build:-}; kube::log::status "${platform}: go build finished" ) &> "/tmp//${platform//\//_}.build" &
    done; local fails=0; for job in $(jobs -p);
    do
        wait ${job} || let "fails+=1";
    done; for platform in "${platforms[@]}";
    do
        cat "/tmp//${platform//\//_}.build";
    done; exit ${fails};
else
    for platform in "${platforms[@]}";
    do
        kube::log::status "Building go targets for ${platform}:" "${targets[@]}"; kube::golang::set_platform_envs "${platform}"; kube::golang::build_binaries_for_platform ${platform} ${use_go_build:-};
    done;
fi )' exited with status 1
Call stack:
  1: /home/peeyush/work/kubernetes/hack/lib/golang.sh:494 kube::golang::build_binaries(...)
  2: /home/peeyush/work/kubernetes/hack/build-go.sh:26 main(...)
Exiting with status 1
!!! Error in ./hack/../hack/update-codegen.sh:32
  '"${KUBE_ROOT}/hack/build-go.sh" ${BUILD_TARGETS[*]}' exited with status 1
Call stack:
  1: ./hack/../hack/update-codegen.sh:32 main(...)
Exiting with status 1
Updating codegen FAILED
```

Any idea what could be the reason behind this? Or how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an environment issue. Cleared everything, cloned the repo afresh and everything is working fine.